# Compare variable start with array key

Tags: php, arrays, regex

There is this array:

```
$array1 = array(51=>1.1, 45=>68, 57=>43, 62=>35, 74=>24);
```

And I want to verify if the value that is taken from the variable starts with any of the keys from the array. (the variable is passing correctly, I checked that)

```
foreach (array_keys($array1) as $key1) {
    if(preg_match("/^[$rvalue]/", $key1))
    {
        $positive1=true; 
        $fvalue1=$array1[$key1];
    }
    else{
        $positive1=false;
        }
}
```

The problem is that it runs all the array and always gives me the value of the last key, instead of one matching the variable.
I'm new with regex, so might be that, don't know. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have square brackets in the regexp?

Comment: @barmar: he wants to make a set of the characters of the value, to check if any key starts with them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems kind of complicated for a simple task. How about at direct comparison:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value) {
    if (substr($rvalue, 0, strlen($key1)) == $key1)
    {
        $fvalue1 = $value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Just break from the loop when you find a match.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the square brackets in the regexp. Also, you're doing the check backwards -- you want to put the keys into the regexp, and match that against the string:

```
if (preg_match("/^$key1/, $rvalue))
```

Square brackets in a regexp are used to match a **single** character that's any one of the characters in the bracket. So `[51]` matches `5` or `1`, but it doesn't match the whole string `51`.

You could also combine all the keys into a single regexp, using `|` in the regexp to specify alternatives:

```
$alternatives = implode('|', array_keys($array1));
if (preg_match("/^(?:$alternatives)/", $rvalue, $match)) {
    $positive1 = true;
    $fvalue1 = $array1[$match[0]];
} else {
    $positive1 = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explication :)